# approaches for solving equations of the form $c^{\top}x$ where both c and x are unknown

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I have to find the minima of the equations of the form 
\begin{equation}
minimize \enspace c^\top x.
\end{equation}
 Here $c$ is an unknown positive real value vector with entries taking value between 0 and 1, and $x$ is an unknown binary random vector. Clearly, when $x$ is unconstrained the minima is 0.

But I do have some restrictions on $x$ and not all the elements can not be zero at the same time.  But of course, these constraints depends on the corresponding values of $c$.

What is the general strategy for finding an approximate solution in these settings ?

Comment: It all depends on what constraints you have on x. For example, you can formulate a problem like vertex cover which would mean you will not be able to minimize it

Comment: @SandeepSilwal, What if the constraints on x are typical facility location constraints

Answer (score 0):

It is going to depend on the sort of constraints you are given in your problem. For example, if these constraints are linear, meaning that they are of the form $A \mathbf{x} \leq \mathbf{b}$ for some vector $\mathbf{b}$, then your problem lies in what is known as *linear programming*. I suggest you to take a look into the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) to see which of the variants mentioned there fits best to your particular case.

You mention in the question that your vector of variables $\mathbf{x}$ is binary, meaning that each $x_i \in \{0,1\}$. Then your problem is a *binary integer programming* problem or *0-1 integer programming*.

If your constraints are non-linear, then your problem is a [nonlinear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_programming) problem. In this case, you might want to take a look at what is known as [Karush-Kuhn-Tucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) conditions which under certain regularity constraints provide necessary conditions for a solution to be optimal.

As for the general strategy to approach this optimization problems, I don't think there isn't one but several different algorithms depending on the problem you want to solve (Simplex algorithm, branch and cut algorithms, cutting-plane...) The Wikipedia article I linked mentions various possibilities.

Comment: I think you did not get the question completely.  c is also unknown.  All my constraints are linear only.  But the fact that c is unknown makes it a non-linear program.  You can think of the problem as an optimization problem of the form $x_1y_1 + x_2y_2$ with constraints on $x$ and $y$